# android studio questions previous button crash

Tags: android-studio, button

```
private val questionBank = listOf(
       Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
       Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
       Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
       Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
       Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
       Question(R.string.question_asia, true))

   private var currentIndex = 0

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)


       binding.trueButton.setOnClickListener { checkAnswer(true) }

       binding.falseButton.setOnClickListener { checkAnswer(false)}

       binding.prevButton.setOnClickListener {
           currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) % questionBank.size
           updateQuestion()
       }

       binding.nextButton.setOnClickListener {
           currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % questionBank.size
           updateQuestion()
       }

       updateQuestion()

   }
```

when I run the android studio, the previous button work fine only when I have select first next button. it will crash if I select first previous button. I am having hard time to figured out the logic behind module calculation what should I add or change where when I press previous button first it will go to last question of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is we should use .mod() instead of %.

````
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1).mod(questionBank.size)
            updateQuestion()
        }

        binding.prevButton.setOnClickListener {
            currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1).mod(questionBank.size)
            updateQuestion()
        }```
````